# How to hide the left pane

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am migrating from SharePoint 2016 to 2019.

My sites are doc libraries and I used Term Store Management to create my menus.

In 2016, my menus only show on top but now that I migrated, I can see the menus on top and on the left.

How do I hide the pane on the left?

Thanks

Christophe
[image]

Comment: You should be able to hide the quick launch from Site settings > navigation or Site settings > Tree view.

Comment: Going to Site settings > navigation brings me to the Term Set area. I don't see a quick launch option available with Term Set

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**:
Depending on the Site Template you used and features that are activated sometimes the "Navigation Elements" link is not visible on the "Site Settings" Page.  But you can always navigate there manually.  Add `/_layouts/15/navoptions.aspx` to the end of your site url, for example, `https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursitename/_layouts/15/navoptions.aspx`

You should see the following page with just two options:

[image: Screenshot of NavOptions.aspx]

Then just uncheck the "Enable Quick Launch" checkbox and click "OK".

**Option 2**:
Go to the All Site Settings page, and under the "Look and Feel" section, choose the option titled "Change the look" -- this will take you to the "_layouts/15/designgallery.aspx" page.  If you do not actually want to change your colors, choose the first option titled "Current".  This brings up another page (see screenshot below") that allows you to choose a new Layout -- choose "Oslo", and hit "Try it out", and eventually "Yes, keep it."

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the trick. Going to /_layouts/15/navoptions.aspx shows that the Quick Launch is still disabled. BTW, I see the left pane in the "New" SharePoint design. If I click to "Return to classic SharePoint", the left pane is hidden as expected. So the problem is in the new 2019 view.

Comment: What template is this built on?  Team, Communication, etc.?  Normally in Modern Sties, we have the opposite problem of figuring out how to turn Quick Launch ON.

Comment: Is the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature enabled in your site?

Comment: I added another option to my answer that uses the Change the look -> Site Layout option, give that a try.

Comment: My sites were built using the Document Center. We use mainly SharePoint to store our important documents. When switching to Oslo, the navigation menu on top disappeared. "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" is Active.